# Python subprocess interaction blocked by stdout.readline()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to use the subprocess module to launch another instances of Pyhton, send commands and retrieve the output. However no matter what I try, it always hangs at `stdout.readline()`. Here's my current attempt:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
script = "import sys;sys.stdout.write('glorp')\n"

p = Popen([r"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe",], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, text=True)
p.stdin.write(script)
print("readline")
print(p.stdout.readline())
print("end")
```

The code never gets past the line involving `readline()`. I've tried using `flush()` on `stdin` and `stdout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that the Python interpreter is not in interactive mode when we start it as a subprocess. As the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#interface-options) notes:

> When called with standard input connected to a tty device, it prompts for commands and executes them

In this case, the subprocess's `stdin` is not connected to a terminal ("tty device"). And

> In non-interactive mode, the entire input is parsed before it is executed.

So Python just sits there and does nothing until `stdin` is closed. But we can force it into interactive mode with the [`-i` command-line option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-i). Then:

> When a script is passed as first argument or the `-c` option is used, enter interactive mode after executing the script or the command, even when `sys.stdin` does not appear to be a terminal.

It's also useful to pass the [`-q` option](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-q)

> Don’t display the copyright and version messages even in interactive mode.

and communicate with the subprocess in unbuffered mode by setting [`bufsize=0`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). Then we are able to have the interpreter run multiple commands and we can inspect the output in between:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['python', '-i', '-q'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, text=True, bufsize=0)

p.stdin.write('print("First line executed.")\n')
print(p.stdout.readline(), end='')

p.stdin.write('print("Second line executed.")\n')
print(p.stdout.readline(), end='')
```

Note that the prompts (`>>>`) may come in out of order in the console:

```
>>> >>> First line executed.
Second line executed.
>>>
```

We could hide the chevrons by adding `'-c', 'import sys; sys.ps1=""'` to the argument list when starting the interpreter.

It is also recommended to explicitly set the encoding as UTF-8 on both ends. A more thorough demonstration can be found in [this issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue45719) on the Python bug tracker.